Overwite PrimeNG component styles directly on HTML template with tailwind
So I'm working with PrimeNG's panel menu component, and I need to apply some styles directly using Tailwind classes instead of inline styles or external CSS.
PrimeNG PanelMenu component
This is my current HTML template:
<p-panelMenu styleClass="w-full" [model]="menuItems()">
      <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item>
        <ng-container>
          @if (item.url) {
            <a
              target="_blank"
              class="align-items-start line-clamp-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium leading-6 text-foreground"
              [href]="item.url"
            >
              <span class="ml-2 line-clamp-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium leading-6 text-foreground">
                {{ item.label | translate }}
              </span>
            </a>
          } @else {
            <span class="align-items-start line-clamp-2 flex cursor-pointer font-medium leading-6 text-foreground">
              <span>{{ item.label | translate }}</span>
              @if (item.items) {
                <ng-icon name="phosphorCaretDown" size="16" class="ml-auto text-primary" />
              }
            </span>
          }
        </ng-container>
      </ng-template>
    </p-panelMenu>

And this is my estyles on style property of angular componente decorator:
styles: [
`
  .p-panelmenu-header-content {
    @apply border-none;
    &:hover {
      @apply bg-transparent;
    }
  }
  .p-panelmenu-content {
    @apply border-none;
  }
  .p-toggleable-content {
    @apply m-0;
  }
  li {
    @apply mt-2;
    a {
      @apply text-title-6 line-clamp-2 flex cursor-pointer leading-6 text-foreground;
    }
  }
`]

I'm trying not to use the styles in the component and do it directly in line with the tailwind classes.
I have tried options such as the following but without getting what I want.
<p-panelMenu
 [styleClass]="'w-full md:w-20rem border-0'"
 class="[&>*]:line-clamp-2 [&>*]:w-full [&>*]:font-medium [&>*]:leading-6 
 [&>*]:text-foreground"
 [model]="menuItems()"
>

Stackblitz with the desire result:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/twnqhi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpanel-menu-template-demo.ts

please share a working example on stackblitz with the issue happening, please share the steps to reproduce the issue, what is wrong with the stackblitz and expected output

I added the stackblitz with the expected output. The wrong result is the default component styles.

is this the expected output stackblitz

Thank you very much. I had to make some more changes because there is CSS at root level but with the change you have told me I have achieved it.

do post an answer, so that it will help others in the future
